# Why is my wp_enqueue_scripts not firing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

Here is my code and it is not firing.  I can directly link the css and get it to show but using the wp_enqueue_script does nothing.

Here is what I have coded.

```
<?php function load_slider(){
  wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); // deregisters the default WordPress jQuery  
  wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"), false);

  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_register_script('flexslider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/javascripts/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array( 'jquery' ), 'v2.20', true);

  wp_register_style('flexstyle', get_template_directory_uri() .'stylesheets/flexslider.css', "", 'v2.2.0', true);       
}

wp_enqueue_script('flexslider');
wp_enqueue_style('flexstyle');

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_slider' );

?>
```

none of this shows in the browser so I know it is not being found.

Comment: Oh, dear... **do not deregister** the bundled jQuery version... & you loading v1.6.2?? You're gonna break a lot of plugins along the way... This is a flucking horrible idea spread by dumb pseudo-developers... *Google, pls, can we has a search/replace in the whole Internet?* --> http://blog.japh.com.au/2012/09/06/problems-with-themes-on-themeforest-are-problems-with-themes/#comment-21

Answer (score -1):

```
function load_slider(){
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); // deregisters the default WordPress jQuery  
    wp_register_script('custom-jquery', "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js", false);

    wp_enqueue_script('custom-jquery');
    wp_register_script('flexslider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/javascripts/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array( 'custom-jquery' ), 'v2.20', true);

    wp_register_style('flexstyle', get_template_directory_uri() .'stylesheets/flexslider.css', "", 'v2.2.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('flexslider');
    wp_enqueue_style('flexstyle');       
}



add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_slider' );
```

Comment: Put both inside the function and same result.  the space was a error on my part putting in the code.

Comment: edit your question and update your code so that i can see, one thing y u r not using default jquery of wordpress ? .. also you can try using diff handle other than `jquery` for your custom jquery script

Comment: only reason i don't have the wp files is because I couldn't get it to work either so tried the google library with exact same results.  Neither the CSS or the .js file are being loaded.

Comment: [-1 for `wp_deregister_script`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692610/why-is-my-wp-enqueue-scripts-not-firing#comment29252546_19692610)